# Creating a programme which counts students using thread

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, count, counter

I am trying to create a program which will give the following output:

```
MathStudent[1] Jack Count: 1
MathStudent[2] Smith Count: 1
MathStudent[3] Victor Count: 1
MathStudent[4] Mike Count: 1
ScienceStudent[5] Dave Count: 1
ScienceStudent[6] Oscar Count: 1
ScienceStudent[7] Peter Count: 1
ComputerStudent[8] Philip Count 1
ComputerStudent[9] Shaun Count 1
ComputerStudent[10] Scott Count 1
MathStudent[1] Jack Count: 2
MathStudent[2] Smith Count: 2
MathStudent[3] Victor Count: 2
MathStudent[4] Mike Count: 2
ScienceStudent[5] Dave Count: 2
ScienceStudent[6] Oscar Count: 2
ScienceStudent[7] Peter Count: 2
ComputerStudent[8] Philip Count 2
ComputerStudent[9] Shaun Count 2
ComputerStudent[10] Scott Count 2
:
:
:
MathStudent[1] Jack Count: 10
MathStudent[2] Smith Count: 10
MathStudent[3] Victor Count: 10
MathStudent[4] Mike Count: 10
ScienceStudent[5] Dave Count: 10
ScienceStudent[6] Oscar Count: 10
ScienceStudent[7] Peter Count: 10
ComputerStudent[8] Philip Count 10
ComputerStudent[9] Shaun Count 10
ComputerStudent[10] Scott Count 10
```

But the Output that I am getting is:

```
MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[5]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[6]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[7]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[8] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[9] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[10] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[11]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[12]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[13]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[14]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[15]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[16]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[17]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[18] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[19] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[20] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[21]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[22]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[23]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[24]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[25]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[26]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[27]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[28] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[29] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[30] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[31]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[32]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[33]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[34]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[35]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[36]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[37]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[38] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[39] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[40] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[41]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[42]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[43]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[44]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[45]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[46]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[47]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[48] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[49] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[50] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[51]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[52]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[53]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[54]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[55]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[56]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[57]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[58] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[59] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[60] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[61]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[62]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[63]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[64]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[65]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[66]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[67]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[68] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[69] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[70] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[71]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[72]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[73]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[74]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[75]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[76]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[77]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[78] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[79] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[80] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[81]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[82]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[83]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[84]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[85]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[86]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[87]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[88] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[89] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[90] Scott:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[91]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[92]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[93]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[94]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[95]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[96]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[97]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[98] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[99] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[100] Scott:  - Count:1
```

The main class is:

```
public class JavaLab5 {
    public static final int DEBUG = 0;
    public static void multipleThreads(int number) {
        StudentThread []st = new StudentThread[number];
        for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
            st[j] = new StudentThread();
            st[j].start();


            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception at PrintThread.run: " + e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //StudentThread studentThread = new StudentThread();
        //studentThread.start();
        multipleThreads(10);
    }

}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {
    static int studentCounter = 1;
    String name;
    private int count = 0;
    public static int instances = 0;

    // Getters
    public  String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        if (JavaLab5.DEBUG > 3) System.out.println("In Student.setName. Name = "+ name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates name,age and gender 
     * with defaults
     */
    public Student() {
        instances++;
        this.name = "Not Set";
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param name String with the name
    */
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Destructor
     * @throws Throwable 
     */
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        //do finalization here
        instances--;
        super.finalize(); //not necessary if extending Object.
    } 

    public void getCounter() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return this.name; 
    }

    public String getSubjects() {
        return this.getSubjects();
    }    
}
```

Computer Student:

```
public class ComputerStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ComputerStudent() {
        super();
    }

    public ComputerStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Computer Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "] " + name + ": "); 
    }
}
```

Math Student:

```
public class MathStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     * @param name
     */
    public MathStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    public MathStudent() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" MathStudent" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": ");
    }
}
```

Science Student:

```
public class ScienceStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ScienceStudent() {
        super();
    }

    public ScienceStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
     @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Science Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": ");
    } 
}
```

StudentThread class:
public class StudentThread extends Thread {

```
public void run(){
    Student s[] = new Student[10];

    s[0] = new MathStudent("Smith");
    s[1] = new MathStudent("Jack");
    s[2] = new MathStudent("Victor");
    s[3] = new MathStudent("Mike");
    s[4] = new ScienceStudent("Dave");
    s[5] = new ScienceStudent("Oscar");
    s[6] = new ScienceStudent("Peter");
    s[7] = new ComputerStudent("Philip");
    s[8] = new ComputerStudent("Shaun");
    s[9] = new ComputerStudent("Scott");

    for (Student item : s) {
        System.out.print(item.getSubjects() + " - " + "Count:");
        item.getCounter();
    }

}
```

}

I have 2 problems, one is that the student number is going all the way upto 100 but it should only go up to 10 and then the set of 10 students should repeast without the student number within the brackets increasing.

And the secound problem is that the count is not going up it is just staying at 1.

Comment: For the second Problem look closer to your `getCounter()` Methode in class `Student`. You are always just iterating once.

Comment: Each Thread creates 10 students = 100 students, and each student calls counter once = 100 students with 100 separate calls to counter = counter always 1.

Comment: @668 how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> The student number is going all the way upto 100 but it should only go
>   up to 10 and then the set of 10 students should repeat without the
>   student number within the brackets increasing.

To fix this problem, you need to create only 10 number of students, but you are currently creating 100 students. You can do this by passing as `multipleThreads(1);` OR just remove the loop `for (int j = 0; j < number; j++)`

> And the second problem is that the count is not going up it is just
>   staying at 1.

Your `count` variable is NOT `static` so it will be created for each `Student` object, so to fix this issue, mark it as static variable i.e., `private static int count = 0;` inside `Student` class.